# Comparing parameters in visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

Trying to compare two parameters from controller in visual force page and wondering if it is at all possible. If yes, please let me know how. Here is my code and error I encounter:

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!myParticipant == !reportKeyParticipant}">
    //do something
</apex:outputPanel>
```

> Error: Incorrect parameter type for function 'not()'. Expected
>   Boolean, received Text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need the exclamation sign (`!`) keyword once, unless you mean to use it as the "not" operator.

Make your code look like this:

`apex:outputPanel rendered="{!myParticipant == reportKeyParticipant}">`

And you'll be fine.